# How can I compute the eigenstates of a tight-binding Hamiltonian describing a system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, tight-binding

I have the following set-up in a 3-site tight-binding system: 
\begin{align}
i\hbar\frac{dc_1}{dt}&=-Ac_2,\\ 
i\hbar\frac{dc_2}{dt}&=-Ac_1-Ac_3,\\
i\hbar\frac{dc_3}{dt}&=-Ac_2,
\end{align}
and $c_1=c_3$. By setting up a tight-binding Hamiltonian:

$$H = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -A & 0 \\ -A & 0 & -A \\ 0 & -A & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

and diagonalising:

$$0 = |H - IE| = \begin{vmatrix}-E & -A & 0 \\ -A & -E & -A \\ 0 & -A & -E \end{vmatrix},$$

I have found the possible energies as $E=\sqrt{2}A$, $E=-\sqrt{2}A$, and $E=0$.

I am unsure of how to compute the eigenstates of this Hamiltonian. I thought of doing $$(H-IE)(\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3)=0$$ to compute them, but this didn't yield any promising results.

Comment: Calculating $(H - IE) (\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3)$ for the three values of $E$ you found is exactly what you need to do.  Can you elaborate on why your results weren't "promising"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought of doing $$(H-IE)(\psi_1, \psi_2, \psi_3)=0$$ to compute them, but this didn't yield any promising results.

That's precisely what you need to do. You formulate the linear equations, giving
$$
\begin{pmatrix}E & -A & 0 \\ -A & E & -A \\ 0 & -A & E\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\psi_1\\ \psi_2 \\ \psi_3\end{pmatrix}
=0,
$$
and you find nonzero solutions. There's nothing for it but to work the algebra until it gives.

In particular, note that unless $E$ is an eigenvalue, the system above is nonsingular, which means that the only possible solution to the homogoeneous problem is $\psi=0$; to get a nonzero solution you *require* the matrix to be singular, which is why you *need* $E$ to be an eigenvalue.

Comment: Awesome. Would there not be $-\sqrt{2}E$, $\sqrt{2}E$ on two of the diagonal zeros?

Comment: @ODP When you calculate the eigenvectors that correspond to those eigenvalues, yes. As the answer states, that equation system is for the $E=0$ eigenvalue.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I just jumped to the good stuff! My only issue now is on how to match the energy eigenstates to the wavefunctions. So for example, I have a case where there are two energy eigenstates, +A and -A. So I end up with the matrix:

$$
A
\begin{pmatrix}-1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}\psi_1 \\ \psi_2 \end{pmatrix}
=0.
$$

This ends up giving me $\psi_1=-\psi_2$ and $\psi_1=\psi_2$. In other words, $\Psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 1)$ or $\Psi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, -1)$. How do I know which $\Psi$ corresponds to $E=A$ and which $\Psi$ corresponds to $E=-A$?

Comment: @ODP uh... I've got no idea what you're doing there. The system you've just written is nonsingular and the only solution is $\Psi=0$ - the states you wrote are not solutions of the system you wrote, and they're not eigenvectors of that matrix. As to how you assign eigenvectors to eigenvalues - if you put in one eigenvalue into the system, you assign the vector to that eigenvalue.